# Determine shape creation with canvas

Tags: javascript

I want to test with JavaScript that a canvas shape was created.

For example: I'm creating a circle:

```
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = this.color;
context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

In this moment circle suppose to be created.
I'm thinking to test it like this:

```
context.isPointInPath(this.x+1,this.y+1) == true;
```

But I don't find this very elegant. 
Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

**x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> < r<sup>2</sup>**

**r - radius**

This is the set of points for a circle.

All the values of **x** and **y** that meets the formula inequality are inside the circle.

So check for a point with values `(-r< x <r,-r< y <r)` to be true.

And check for points `(r+1,r+1)` `(r+1,-r-1)` `(-r-1,r+1)` `(-r-1,-r-1)` to be false

Comment: You mean check by using isPointInPath ?

Comment: Yep, `isPointInPath`. Perhaps `(r+1,r+1)` instead of `(r+0.1,r+0.1)` would be better, maybe integer are better for pixels